# The height and width properties on my Flex 4 app are not working?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

In the opening application tag of my Flex 4 app, I set the width and height properties as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           creationComplete="init()"
           backgroundColor.mainState="0x303030"
           xmlns:components="components.*"
           width="798"
           height="240">
```

What I go into Design mode in Flash Builder 4, the app is the correct size. But when I embed the .swf file into a HTML page, the application's background color covers the whole screen, and when the Flash Player Settings message box pops up it is outside of the area I defined in the code above. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you resolved this?  I'm having the same problem.  Despite my explicit sizes in the Application, the generated HTML file always contains height="100%" and width="100%".

Answer (score 0):

Check the index.template.html in the html-template folder. That's the file that generates your index.html when you build; perhaps you could address your problems in there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Flex Application width and height to 100%.

> No matter what, the html template's width and height are always 100%,
>      you have to set the flex application width and height to 100%. Flex
>      Application itself cannot render on the browser. It needs some kind
>      of wrapper to render it on the browser. Hence Flex Application gets
>      wrapped inside an HTML template and the Browser eventually renders
>      the Flex Application.

**Flex Application** --> **HTML Template** --> **Browser**